# Nested <img> within <noscript> still making network request

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript-generated `<img>` within a `<noscript>`. I would expect that there is no network request for the image unless JavaScript was disabled. However, I'm seeing both network requests occur (when I would only expect one).

What am I not understanding?

Here's a [Codepen rep](https://codepen.io/skube/pen/PoXNGJR)
[image]

```js
const noScriptEl = document.createElement("noscript");
const imgEl = document.createElement("img");
imgEl.src = "https://placehold.co/1";
document.body.appendChild(noScriptEl).appendChild(imgEl);
```

```html
<p>The 20x20 should always make a network request
<img src="https://placehold.co/20" alt=""></p>

<p>The JS added 1x1 shouldn't make any network request</p>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed.

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. They can't be copy/pasted to build test cases, don't show up in searches, may be blocked for users on networks without access to some other websites, and are invisible to screen readers / braille keyboards / etc. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself.

Comment: .... using script to insert a <noscript> tag. That's something I've not seen before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically generated image elements always load their source, even if the element isn't added to the DOM.

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/20/20';
img.onload = function () { console.log(this.width); } 
/* The browser can't calculate the width of the image unless  
   it accesses it over the network. Since it shows the width,
   we know it accesses it over the network. */
```

Consequently, adding such an image to the DOM in a place where it usually wouldn't be loaded has no influence over it being loaded or not.